# Implementing delegates within the class (iOS/Swift)

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, delegates

In mobile development, interfaces and delegates are implemented as follows *(using the location service as an example)*:

***1. Android, Java***

```
    public class myClass implements LocationListener {      
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {          
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }   
    }
```

***1. iOS, Swift***

```
    class myVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, 
                             didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        }
    }
```

What would be the iOS/Swift equivalent of this type of Android implementation:

***2. Android, Java***

```
    public class myClass {      
        LocationListener GPS = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {          
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }               
        }
    }
```

***2. iOS, Swift?***

```
    class myVC: UIViewController {
       ???
    }
```

I'm not academically-trained, so my programming lingo is **really** bad. Could anyone also please help explain the differences between these two types of implementations, and what they are called?

*Much TIA.*

Comment: var delegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate?

would Highly recommend to read the swift documentation first before you start https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: `LocationListener` This is `interface`  , `CLLocationManagerDelegate ` This is `Protocol` There is a big difference between them . read this https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Swift-Protocols-and-Java-Interface

Comment: Not the difference between the two languages. What's the difference between placing them at the top of the class and instantiating them within the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, a protocol, such as `CLLocationManagerDelegate` provides a blueprint of "stuff" that a class, struct or enum must implement to say it "conforms" to that specific protocol. (It could also have optional methods that are not required to be implemented.)

In your first example:

```
class myVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate { }
```

`myVC` is saying that it implements/conforms-to protocol `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. For this, it **must** implement any required methods of that protocol and might implement any **optional** ones too; such as `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`.

If I understand your question, you would like to know if you might end up implementing `myClass` without saying it implements `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Something like this:

```
class myVC: UIViewController {
   var locationManagerDelegate = SomethingImplementingTheDelegate()
}

class SomethingImplementingTheDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { /*...*/ }
}
```

As you can see, you still need some class/struct/enum that **implements** what the protocol/delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate` says, since (a protocol) it's just a blueprint.

(Technical note: Protocols can provide some implementation through protocol extensions, but it is for conforming types, you still can't instantiate a protocol).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enhance how location work with IOS then you can do by this way

Add these lines in Info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Step : 1

```
Declare the delegate in class where you need location update
Let say 

class LocationPickerViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

1.1 -  Declare the locationManager object

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Step : 2

```
Define one method where you configure all this for Location method
let say

func setupLocationAcess()
{
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Step : 3
    Define this method to viewWillAppear

Step : 4
    Implement delegate method in your class

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations 
locations: [CLLocation]) 
{
    guard let location = locations.first else { return }
    currentLocationListeners.forEach { $0.action(location) }
    currentLocationListeners = currentLocationListeners.filter { !$0.once }
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I hope it will help you